# Is it possible to inject variable inside src in img with Alpine.js from a for loop?

Tags: html, nunjucks, alpine.js

I am running a for loop with Alpine.js. I am using the Nunjucks template engine.

I have an array with three items called items

Is it possible to inject the item variable in the src attribute of the img tag? See code below.

```
<div x-data="{items: ['first-image.png','second-image.png','third-image.png'], active: 0}">
<div class="snap overflow-auto relative flex-no-wrap flex transition-all" x-ref="slider"
    x-on:scroll.debounce="active = Math.round($event.target.scrollLeft / ($event.target.scrollWidth / items.length))">
    <template x-for="(item,index) in items" :key="index">
        <div class="w-full flex-shrink-0 flex items-center justify-center">
            <img src="`../assets/images/favicon/${item}`" alt="" style="height:550px">
        </div>
    </template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely possible, what you're looking for is the `x-bind` directive.

You can "bind" a value from your Alpine.js component state to the `src` attribute using `x-bind:src="someValue"` or `:src=""` in shorthand

So you can do:

```html
<img x-bind:src="`../assets/images/favicon/${item}`" alt="" style="height:550px">
```

Comment: Yes this is correct. Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for.